# Adding an entry to the Linux Kernel .config file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How can I manually add the line CONFIG_XILINX_FIXED_DEVTREE_ADDR=y to the linux config file? It keeps getting overwritten when I build the kernel

Comment: Don't add it manually.  Use `make menuconfig`.  See: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/kconfig.html

Comment: How do you try to build the kernel?

Answer (score 2):

You can build by `make CONFIG_XILINX_FIXED_DEVTREE_ADDR=y` without adding it into *.config*. But if you gonna add it to .config, you should use `make menuconfig` to select it and save it into *.config*.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm at the menuconfig right now, where exactly would I place this entry at?

Comment: @YoungdoLee, Not necessary. You may add manually entire Kconfig tree which leads to certain option be enabled.

Comment: @JonSherman I don't know where it is, because I don't have your kernel. But you can find where your config is by pressing `/` in menuconfig and then typing the keyword. In your case `XILINX_FIXED_DEVTREE_ADDR`. The menuconfig console will show where it is.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko Yes. But IMHO, if I am a user or builder(not developer for that kernel tree), i think using menuconfig is better than editing .config or Kconfig or *_defconfig. In this backound, I recommended above method.

Comment: @YoungdoLee, I tried searching for it, and there's no matching results. The XILINX_FIXED_DEVTREE_ADDR is not an entry in the .config file, I'm trying to add it though.

Answer (score 0):

If the config variable you're trying to add is new (as in, not in `.config` at all and not showing up in `make menuconfig`), then you should add it to the relevant Kconfig file. For instance, if you look at `fs/proc/Kconfig`, you can see how different `proc` config options are laid out. Follow their example and add your config variable, its variable type, the default, and its description. Then you should see it in `make menuconfig`.

Here's an example of a config variable definition in `fs/proc/Kconfig`:

```
config PROC_VMCORE
    bool "/proc/vmcore support"
    depends on PROC_FS && CRASH_DUMP
    default y
    help
      Exports the dump image of crashed kernel in ELF format.
```