# Linux Kernel: update config from command line for specific modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

To build the linux kernel from source, I would normally do something like:

```
make mrproper
make menuconfig
make
```

In the menuconfig step, I enable some modules I want to have built into the kernel that aren't part of the default config file (defconfig).

Now suppose I know in advance what modules I want to enable in menuconfig, but want to automate the build process from a script (i.e. non-interactively). I don't want to edit the .config file manually before issuing make as I may not correctly resolve the dependencies of the modules I want to install.

Is there some way of replacing the menuconfig step with something like

make updateconfig module_name

?

PS I don't want to do menuconfig the first time and then save the updated .config as a new default config.

Comment: Create once a config file and run `make olddefconfig` each time you want to update the kernel. And why you don't want to go this direction?

Comment: I ended up doing something like this. My process was: make mrproper; merge some default config files to create a new .config; make olddefconfig in order to specify any remaining options non-interactively; make

Comment: Btw, you might put in your local branch something like `tiny.config` and adjust `scripts/kconfig/Makefile` to support it in the same way. In this case you will never have a conflicts if your "third-party" defconfig file has been changed.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the answer to [Adding an entry to the Linux Kernel .config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491596/adding-an-entry-to-the-linux-kernel-config-file?rq=1)

i.e. you can do:

make CONFIG_XILINX_FIXED_DEVTREE_ADDR=y

and the specified module option will be compiled in. Presumably this also takes care of the module dependencies; I've tried it on a module with some dependencies and it seems to work ok.

Comment: So, for module we need: `make CONFIG_XILINX_FIXED_DEVTREE_ADDR=m modules`?

Comment: This way is bad since you have to know ahead what dependencies are. OTOH it is one good for fast compilation test of module in question.

Comment: The main reason I needed it is because I am compiling a third-party linux distribution from source but I don't want to change the third-party defconfig file. I suppose a better way would be to create a version-controlled vendor branch and commit changes to that.

Comment: And why is it the problem (I mean modifying defconfig)? Are they using Git or not? 
Btw, I'm using several branches based on let's say "third-party" Linux kernel, though it's just a plain upstream. I do update my local branch whenever I need to adjust my configuration. An example: https://github.com/andy-shev/linux/commits/eds

Comment: It's not a problem, I just haven't done it that way yet. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4):

**make menuconfig** is one of five similar tools that can configure the Linux kernel source, a necessary early step needed to compile the source code. make menuconfig, with a menu-driven user interface, allows the user to choose the features of the Linux kernel (and other options) that will be compiled.

**make menuconfig** is tool which will load all attribute which define in **Kconfig** and create new **.config**. First you will have to add your attribute to Kconfig then it'll show in menuconfig.

```
 Example :
 I want to add new backlight driver in kernel.
 1. open Kconfig 'drivers/video/backlight/Kconfig' and add below line---

    config BACKLIGHT_LOCOMO
    tristate "Sharp LOCOMO LCD/Backlight Driver"
    depends on SHARP_LOCOMO
    default y
    help
      If you have a Sharp Zaurus SL-5500 (Collie) or SL-5600 (Poodle) say y to
      enable the LCD/backlight driver.

    2. Add CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_LOCOMO to make file.
        obj-$(CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_LOCOMO) += locomolcd.o
```

Now run **make mrproper** and **make menuconfig**. It'll show in menu.

---

Otherwise you can manually add to .config '**CONFIG_BACKLIGHT_LOCOMO=y**'.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [config](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/config) script in the tree that allows callers to enable and disable options in `.config` from the shell. It doesn't look like it does any dependency resolution, though, so perhaps it makes sense to run `make olddefconfig` after using it, as other comments mention.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the [merge_config.sh](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh) script in the tree that allows to merge an additional config-fragment file to your config. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39440863/12472865) for details.